# Formato json llega con valores null desde consumo rest pero desde postman sirve

Tags: java, json, rest

Buen día.
Estoy realizando una api rest y una que consume el service rest, mi problema es el trabajo con el json al enviarlo desde una app que lo consume pero si pruebo el service rest desde postman los datos si llegan no entiendo el por que.

El json lo es de la siguiente manera
`{"apellidos":"Mendez","correo":"alvaro@hotmail.com","nombres":"Alvaro"}` y si lo envio desde postman si llegan el json bien ese mismo.

El código del rest es:

```
@PostMapping (consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public CUsuarioVO registrarUsuario(@RequestBody CUsuarioVO usvo) {

        System.out.println("LLEGADA AL METODO PostMapping");
        usuariovo.setNombres(usvo.getNombres());
        usuariovo.setApellidos(usvo.getApellidos());
        usuariovo.setCorreo(usvo.getCorreo());

        return usuariovo;
    }
```

Y desde este código no sirve no entiendo el por que llegan los valores el json en null

```
public static void restPostUsuario() {

            // // Envia el json con los datos al service @PostMapping
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
                json.put("correo", "alejogmailcom");
                json.put("nombres", "Alejandro");
                json.put("apellidos", "Garcia");
               
                System.out.println(json); // = {"apellidos":"Perez","correo":"manuelpe@gmail.com","nombres":"Manuel"}

                
String resultado = rest.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/appday/usuarios", json, String.class);
System.out.println("El resultado del post service rest es : " + resultado);
// El resultado del post service rest es :{"nombres":null,"apellidos":null,"correo":null}
               
            } catch (JSONException | RestClientException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR EN EL CONSUMO DEL REST POST : " + e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que desde `Postman` si puedes acceder a `http://localhost` y puedes realizar la petición en : `http://localhost:8080/appday/usuarios`

si realizas la petición dentro de la app no puedes acceder a `http://localhost`, te sugiero publiques la página en un dominio publico y este será alcanzado por la app.

o realizar el siguiente procedimiento:

[**Comenzar con la depuración remota de dispositivos Android**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging?utm_campaign=2016q3&utm_medium=redirect&utm_source=dcc#reverse-port-forwarding)

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, No comprendo lo que dices, ya lo hice asi muchas veces incluso el dia de antier em sirvió a la perfección ya lo echo varias veces en mi propio localhost, el service rest lo hice en Spring Tool y lo consumo desde Una app de apache netbeans con springframework y sirvio pero lo estoy haciendo de nuevo y dejo de servirme incluso me esta dando un error el metodo dos desde donde consumo el servicio, -> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.json.JSONObject]

Comment: Incluso tengo varios el get, el delete y el put y me funcionan a la perfeccion desde el localhost, el error es con el json al enviarlo desde la app que lo consume, pero desde postman si me recibe el json.

Comment: Desde tu dispositivo pudiste realizar anteriormente la petición a http://localhost:8080/appday/usuarios ?

Comment: Si si lo hice hace 3 dias, incluso aun me funciona me sirve normal los metodos rest = delete, put y get solo me falta que me sirva el @PostMapping para recibir el json y el json lo recibe normal desde postman funciona bien pero ese mismo json que envio desde de netbeans me da el error que te mencione arriba es como si no enviara un json lo estoy haciendo con la libreria JsonObject de java ->  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); json.put("correo", "alejogmailcom");
                json.put("nombres", "Alejandro");

Comment: Ya le hice con esa libreria y con la de Gson de google igual pero sigue sin recibirlo